# show images in html email in gnus using w3m

Tags: emacs, gnus

I just started using gnus and would like to see images in html email. I set

```
(setq mm-text-html-renderer 'w3m)
(setq gnus-inhibit-images nil)
```

in my .gnus.el, but I still can't see images. If I press T in the Article, it tells me

```
"There are some images considered unsafe; use the prefix arg to force display."
```

I have unfortunately no idea what to do with this info.

Is there any way that I can enable showing images in w3m if I think it is save, without using K H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the prefix argument by pressing <kbd>C-u</kbd> before the command (so you should press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in your case).

Please refer to the [emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Arguments) for more information on prefix arguments.